# Module not found for package dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack, swiper.js

When compile with webpack i have the error below.
I do not have swiper in my **package.json** but it used by one of my dependency.
Swiper and all 25 modules error like one below are existing in my **node_modules** folder

> Compiled with problems:
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/myDependencyPackage/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./react/swiper-react.js is not exported from package c:...\myAppFolder\node_modules\swiper (see exports field in c:...\myAppFolder\node_modules\swiper\package.json)

Here some of my environement informations

**environement:**

- NodeJS 16
- React 17.0.2
- Webpack ^5.88.0
- Swiper 8.4.7

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "strict": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "listFiles": false,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "paths": {
      "src": ["src"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**webpack.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { GitRevisionPlugin } = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');
const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
const gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin({ commithashCommand: 'rev-parse --short HEAD' });

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port: 8000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true
    },
    entry: {
        index: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.tsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, './public/build'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            'src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
        },
        fallback: {
            crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify")
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: false,
                            happyPackMode: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader",],
            },
            {
                test: /\.md$/,
                use: ['html!markdown-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: ['svg-inline-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|mp3)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: './appsettings.json',
                    to: './appsettings.json'
                },
                {
                    from: './public/favicon.ico',
                    to: './favicon.ico'
                }]
        }),
        gitRevisionPlugin,
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.COMMITHASH': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
            'process.env.BRANCH': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.branch()),
        }),

    ]
};
```

Solution i try

- adding swiper into my **package.json**
- adding **import** or call **require** method in my app
- testing different configuration on my **tsconfig.json** or **webpack.js**
- clean modules

  - Remove your node_modules folder (rm -rf node_modules)
  - npm cache clean -f
  - npm install
  - npm install firebase-admin
- override swiper version by upgrade or downgrade in my own **package.json**

### [EDIT]

For test, i try to edit **package.json** of swiper in my **node_modules** and fix issues.
But we all know that editing files in node_modules is not a solution.
I added in **exports** line like this

```
"./react/swiper-react.js": "./react/swiper-react.js"
```

**full swiper package.json**

```
{
  "name": "swiper",
  "version": "8.4.7",
  "description": "Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions",
  "typings": "swiper.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./swiper.esm.js",
  "module": "./swiper.esm.js",
  "svelte": "./swiper.esm.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./core": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./swiper.esm.js": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./bundle": "./swiper-bundle.esm.js",
    "./swiper-bundle.esm.js": "./swiper-bundle.esm.js",
    "./css": "./swiper.min.css",
    "./swiper.min.css": "./swiper.min.css",
    "./swiper.css": "./swiper.css",
    "./css/bundle": "./swiper-bundle.min.css",
    "./swiper-bundle.min.css": "./swiper-bundle.min.css",
    "./swiper-bundle.css": "./swiper-bundle.css",
    "./css/a11y": "./modules/a11y/a11y.min.css",
    "./css/autoplay": "./modules/autoplay/autoplay.min.css",
    "./css/controller": "./modules/controller/controller.min.css",
    "./css/effect-coverflow": "./modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.min.css",
    "./css/effect-cube": "./modules/effect-cube/effect-cube.min.css",
    "./css/effect-fade": "./modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.min.css",
    "./css/effect-flip": "./modules/effect-flip/effect-flip.min.css",
    "./css/effect-creative": "./modules/effect-creative/effect-creative.min.css",
    "./css/effect-cards": "./modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.min.css",
    "./css/free-mode": "./modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css",
    "./css/grid": "./modules/grid/grid.min.css",
    "./css/hash-navigation": "./modules/hash-navigation/hash-navigation.min.css",
    "./css/history": "./modules/history/history.min.css",
    "./css/keyboard": "./modules/keyboard/keyboard.min.css",
    "./css/lazy": "./modules/lazy/lazy.min.css",
    "./css/manipulation": "./modules/manipulation/manipulation.min.css",
    "./css/mousewheel": "./modules/mousewheel/mousewheel.min.css",
    "./css/navigation": "./modules/navigation/navigation.min.css",
    "./css/pagination": "./modules/pagination/pagination.min.css",
    "./css/parallax": "./modules/parallax/parallax.min.css",
    "./css/scrollbar": "./modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.min.css",
    "./css/thumbs": "./modules/thumbs/thumbs.min.css",
    "./css/virtual": "./modules/virtual/virtual.min.css",
    "./css/zoom": "./modules/zoom/zoom.min.css",
    "./less": "./swiper.less",
    "./less/a11y": "./modules/a11y/a11y.less",
    "./less/autoplay": "./modules/autoplay/autoplay.less",
    "./less/controller": "./modules/controller/controller.less",
    "./less/effect-coverflow": "./modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.less",
    "./less/effect-cube": "./modules/effect-cube/effect-cube.less",
    "./less/effect-fade": "./modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.less",
    "./less/effect-flip": "./modules/effect-flip/effect-flip.less",
    "./less/effect-creative": "./modules/effect-creative/effect-creative.less",
    "./less/effect-cards": "./modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.less",
    "./less/free-mode": "./modules/free-mode/free-mode.less",
    "./less/grid": "./modules/grid/grid.less",
    "./less/hash-navigation": "./modules/hash-navigation/hash-navigation.less",
    "./less/history": "./modules/history/history.less",
    "./less/keyboard": "./modules/keyboard/keyboard.less",
    "./less/lazy": "./modules/lazy/lazy.less",
    "./less/manipulation": "./modules/manipulation/manipulation.less",
    "./less/mousewheel": "./modules/mousewheel/mousewheel.less",
    "./less/navigation": "./modules/navigation/navigation.less",
    "./less/pagination": "./modules/pagination/pagination.less",
    "./less/parallax": "./modules/parallax/parallax.less",
    "./less/scrollbar": "./modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.less",
    "./less/thumbs": "./modules/thumbs/thumbs.less",
    "./less/virtual": "./modules/virtual/virtual.less",
    "./less/zoom": "./modules/zoom/zoom.less",
    "./scss": "./swiper.scss",
    "./scss/a11y": "./modules/a11y/a11y.scss",
    "./scss/autoplay": "./modules/autoplay/autoplay.scss",
    "./scss/controller": "./modules/controller/controller.scss",
    "./scss/effect-coverflow": "./modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.scss",
    "./scss/effect-cube": "./modules/effect-cube/effect-cube.scss",
    "./scss/effect-fade": "./modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.scss",
    "./scss/effect-flip": "./modules/effect-flip/effect-flip.scss",
    "./scss/effect-creative": "./modules/effect-creative/effect-creative.scss",
    "./scss/effect-cards": "./modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.scss",
    "./scss/free-mode": "./modules/free-mode/free-mode.scss",
    "./scss/grid": "./modules/grid/grid.scss",
    "./scss/hash-navigation": "./modules/hash-navigation/hash-navigation.scss",
    "./scss/history": "./modules/history/history.scss",
    "./scss/keyboard": "./modules/keyboard/keyboard.scss",
    "./scss/lazy": "./modules/lazy/lazy.scss",
    "./scss/manipulation": "./modules/manipulation/manipulation.scss",
    "./scss/mousewheel": "./modules/mousewheel/mousewheel.scss",
    "./scss/navigation": "./modules/navigation/navigation.scss",
    "./scss/pagination": "./modules/pagination/pagination.scss",
    "./scss/parallax": "./modules/parallax/parallax.scss",
    "./scss/scrollbar": "./modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss",
    "./scss/thumbs": "./modules/thumbs/thumbs.scss",
    "./scss/virtual": "./modules/virtual/virtual.scss",
    "./scss/zoom": "./modules/zoom/zoom.scss",
    "./angular": "./angular/fesm2015/swiper_angular.mjs",
    "./react": "./react/swiper-react.js",
    "./vue": "./vue/swiper-vue.js",
    "./solid": "./solid/swiper-solid.js",
    "./svelte": "./svelte/swiper-svelte.js",
    "./types": "./types/index.d.ts",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "angular": [
        "angular/swiper_angular.d.ts"
      ],
      "react": [
        "react/swiper-react.d.ts"
      ],
      "svelte": [
        "svelte/swiper-svelte.d.ts"
      ],
      "solid": [
        "solid/swiper-solid.d.ts"
      ],
      "vue": [
        "vue/swiper-vue.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node -e \"try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "swiper",
    "swipe",
    "slider",
    "touch",
    "ios",
    "mobile",
    "cordova",
    "phonegap",
    "app",
    "framework",
    "framework7",
    "carousel",
    "gallery",
    "plugin",
    "react",
    "solid-js",
    "vue",
    "angular",
    "svelte",
    "slideshow"
  ],
  "author": "Vladimir Kharlampidi",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://swiperjs.com",
  "funding": [
    {
      "type": "patreon",
      "url": "https://www.patreon.com/swiperjs"
    },
    {
      "type": "open_collective",
      "url": "http://opencollective.com/swiper"
    }
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dom7": "^4.0.4",
    "ssr-window": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's used by your dependency, why don't you just add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found with alias resolve in webpack configuration.

```
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            'src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
            'swiper/react/swiper-react.js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js'),
            'swiper/modules/a11y/a11y.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/a11y/a11y.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/autoplay/autoplay.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/autoplay/autoplay.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/controller/controller.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/controller/controller.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-cube/effect-cube.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-cube/effect-cube.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-fade/effect-fade.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-flip/effect-flip.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-flip/effect-flip.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-creative/effect-creative.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-creative/effect-creative.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/grid/grid.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/grid/grid.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/hash-navigation/hash-navigation.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/hash-navigation/hash-navigation.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/history/history.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/history/history.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/keyboard/keyboard.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/keyboard/keyboard.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/lazy/lazy.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/lazy/lazy.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/manipulation/manipulation.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/manipulation/manipulation.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/mousewheel/mousewheel.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/mousewheel/mousewheel.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/parallax/parallax.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/parallax/parallax.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/scrollbar/scrollbar.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/thumbs/thumbs.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/thumbs/thumbs.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/virtual/virtual.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/virtual/virtual.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/zoom/zoom.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/zoom/zoom.min.css'),
            'swiper/modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.min.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.min.css'),
        },
```